# Not able to change the background color of a particular item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to change the background color of a particular recyclerview's item. But I don't why some items are also changing its background color for no reasons.

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int i) {
// 
 if (i==2)
        {
            holder.favoriteBtn.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

        }
}
```

Based on my scenario, I only want to change the color of item number 2..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution ...
We just need to stop recyclerview to recyle our items.. we can do so by writing the following line in onBindViewHolder() method of your adapter.

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. Instead, you should put an `else` on that `if` to set the background to the default color for the other positions.

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole point of a `RecyclerView`, to reuse similar `View`s, so you don't end up with a bunch of off-screen `View`s in memory. You wanna create just enough to fill the on-screen space (plus a couple more to "fill in the gaps" when scrolling), then update those `View`s for their particular positions in `onBindViewHolder()`.